# Как правильно заменять значения в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, index

Исходник:

```
base = [['Number >', ['123','456','789']], ['Number <', ['987', '654', '321']], ["Number = 0", ["1/1", "2/2", "3/3"]]]

print(base)
print(base[0][1][0])

base.insert([0][1][0], '1290')
print(base)
```

Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../Insert.py", line 7, in <module>
    base.insert([0][1][0], '1290')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Как правильно заменять значения в списке?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы хотите кодом изменить список чтобы получился: `base = [['Number >', ['1290', '123','456','789']], ...` ?

Comment: Заменить а не добавить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После уточнения вопроса, предлагаю решение:

```
base[0][1][0] = '1290'
print(base)  # [['Number >', ['1290', '456', '789']],  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в `base.insert([0][1][0], '1290')`, а именно в `[0][1][0]`

---

Разберу по порядку что творится в `[0][1][0]`:

- `[0]` – создание списка с элементом 0
- `[0][1]` – обращение по индексу 1 у списка [0], а это генерирует исключение `IndexError: list index out of range`

Проверка:

```
[0][1]
```

Comment: Как тогда решить эту проблему?

Comment: @оаавирыыва, ... и определиться что вам нужно сделать с списком

Comment: Мне нужно на индексе (Например: [0][1][0]) заменить строку на что-то (Например: "123")

Comment: insert добавляет новый элемент, а не заменяет

Comment: А как тогда заменить?

Comment: Понял спасибо..